# ASP.NET how to check type of the file type irrespective of extension

Tags: c#, asp.net

If somebody renames the extension of any file (other than excel) to xls and xlsx (please dont ask me why :-( ), I need to check for its validity (if that is still a valid excel file). I am using mime type and Its not working. Am I missing anything?

```
const string excel2007MimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
const string excel2003MimeType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

  string excelExtention = string.Empty;
            excelExtention = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(myFilePath.PostedFile.FileName).ToLower();
            string mimeType = myFilePath.PostedFile.ContentType;
            Response.Write("mime type" + mimeType + Environment.NewLine);
            if( 
                 (
                    !(excelExtention == ".xls" && mimeType == excel2003MimeType)
                    ||
                    !(excelExtention == ".xlsx" && mimeType == excel2007MimeType)
                 )
              )
            {
                Response.Write ("only excel file is permitted");
            }
```

I rename a jpg file to xlsx file and upload. If I print out variable mimetype, Its value is "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet". I am not sure why because the content is not an excel file. Its an image.

Comment: "its not working". What exactly is not working?

Comment: When the user uploads a file, the MIME type will be set by the extension and the user's registry; it won't indicate a valid file.  It's not working because it's the wrong approach.

Comment: @Kieren, thanks. I thought so. Is there a better approach?

Comment: @Kieren, I see your answer, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do that you'd need to attempt to open it using an Excel library, or Excel COM object itself.  Microsoft doesn't support Office COM object automation in a server environment, unfortunately.

You could just read the first part of the file and check for a binary signature, but it would be a lot of work to support all possible XLS versions; and .XSLX files are simply ZIP files containing the document in several parts.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You could always use the [Excel OleDB Database driver](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel) and try to open an [OleDbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection(VS.71).aspx) against it.