# How to get file type in file upload control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am used in file upload control. i got the File Name for `CreateDataBase.docx` . 
Now I want the `fileType` for `docx`

I have  `CreateDataBase.docx`  .I just want this file type or i want to  remove `CreateDataBase`

**I have lot of file for xml,pdf,docx,etc .** .So **I want the file type or next characters of dot(.)**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check type of uploaded file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444477/check-type-of-uploaded-file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can simply use

```
System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName)
```

or you can simply perform

```
 string[] segments= FileUpload1.FileName.Split(".");
 string fileExt = segments[segments.Length-1]
```

Answer (score 3):

try the follwoing

```
 String FileExtension =System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
```